# Is there total size limit for S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am wondering if there is size limit for S3 bucket? or I can store object limitless?

I need this information to assure I need to write a cleaner tool or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can store unlimited objects in your S3 bucket. However, there are limits on individual objects stored -

1. An object can be 0 bytes to 5TB.
2. The largest object that can be uploaded in a single PUT is 5 gigabytes
3. For objects larger than 100 megabytes, customers should consider using the Multipart Upload capability.

If you have too many objects then consider randomizing some prefix to your object names.

> When your workload is a mix of request types, introduce some randomness to key names by adding a hash string as a prefix to the key name. By introducing randomness to your key names the I/O load will be distributed across multiple index partitions. For example, you can compute an MD5 hash of the character sequence that you plan to assign as the key and add 3 or 4 characters from the hash as a prefix to the key name.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-performance-improve/

Comment: I am wondering up to which volume 'unlimited' is truly unlimited. Is that a real maximum size per bucket ? You cannot probably store 10^10^10 bytes...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store object limitless.

BTW, if your consideration is performance, see
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event.html